# Android create a different res folder that can be used as resources

Tags: android

I am using two flavors, flavor1 and flavor2

In my flavor2, I have the code below configured in build.gradle. This is so that my flavor2 will actually directly use resources in flavor1.

```
sourceSets {
    falvor2 {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/flavor1/res', 'src/flavor2/res']
    }
}
```

There are certain color definitions that should be different for flavor1 and flavor2. So what I am thinking is that, I should be adding a new resource folder for flavor1. And define any different colors there. And my flavor2 can be kept as is and define the same colors with different values.

```
sourceSets {
    flavor1 {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/flavor1/res', 'src/flavor1/uniqueRes']
    }
    flavor2 {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/flavor1/res', 'src/flavor2/res']
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work in flavor1, Android studio is complaining on build time, saying all the colors I defined in src/flavor1/uniqueRes doesn't exist!

Is there some other configurations that i need to do to add another res folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, the folder needs to be created this way:

1. Click on flavor1 folder
2. File -> New -> Folder -> Res Folder